# Why element order in union type has changed?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

let's assume next type:

```js
type Indexed<A> = A extends any[] ? A[number] : never;

type R = Indexed<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]>
```

If you hover mouse in your IDE or TS playground, you will see `type R = 5 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4`

5 is on the first place

If you change R to `type R = Last<[1, 2, 0, 3, 5]>`,  you will see `type R = 0 | 5 | 1 | 2 | 3`

I understand, that union type order does not matter,
but:

**Why union type order has changed?**

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17944 - looks related...

Comment: Yes, thats it. Thanks!