# How to declare an array of exactly one alias declared in a type alias

Tags: typescript

If I have a TypeScript type alias defined like this:

```
export type PlatformType = 'em' | 'ea' | 'hi';
```

how can I declare a property in an interface so that that property is an array of exactly one type of each `PlatformType` alias? For example, I want this:

```
export interface Constants {
  platformTypes: PlatformType[]; // how to declare a type for platformTypes?
}
```

so that when I have an object of `Constants` type, I need to have this:

```
export const constants: Constants = {
  platformTypes: ['em', 'ea', 'hi']
}
```

Basically, I would like to get an error if I have this:

```
export const constants: Constants = {
  platformTypes: ['em', 'ea'] // should error, missing 'hi'
}
```

or

```
export const constants: Constants = {
  // this will error anyway because 'extra' doesn't belong to PlatformType alias
  platformTypes: ['em', 'ea', 'hi', 'extra']
}
```

or

```
export const constants: Constants = {
  platformTypes: ['em', 'em', 'ea', 'hi'] // should error, duplicate 'em'
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform union type to tuple type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should define a permutation of all allowed tuples.

For instance, if you have a union of three elements you need to create at least 6 tuples:

```js
["em", "ea", "hi"] | ["em", "hi", "ea"] | ["ea", "em", "hi"] | ["ea", "hi", "em"] | ["hi", "em", "ea"] | ["hi", "ea", "em"]
```

This is because union is unordered data structure.

```js
export type PlatformType = 'em' | 'ea' | 'hi';


// credits goes to https://twitter.com/WrocTypeScript/status/1306296710407352321
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
    [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];

export interface Constants {
  platformTypes: TupleUnion<PlatformType>; // how to declare a type for platformTypes?
}

export const constants: Constants = {
  platformTypes: ['em', 'ea', 'hi'] // ok
}

export const constants2: Constants = {
  platformTypes: ['em', 'ea'] // error
}

export const constants3: Constants = {
  platformTypes: ['em', 'ea', 'hi', 'extra'] // error
}

export const constants4: Constants = {
  platformTypes: ['em', 'em', 'ea', 'hi'] // error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKAbAhjAZtAWwBVlUBeOAcmAMrgB8rgs7HKALAS0oG4AoAQHpBcAMZRgAE04wAznADmEYPJgQ47GDDCyAXMJgB3GTGBQAdKIgFBAdSgRRJFAGVxnMDEGyYOAK6yggCMAMwADABsAEwAnBEA7EFhACxh8SEArFEhUUF8SChwRH5gGMAAqgB2nBCVADzlcKCmlZLyPlCclQoANHAASk0gLW1wWJWIANoAunAUMwB8c3AA3nwAkJMucF1w5dO6cACiIKIYfpLADX0uS83ArfKVwABuZnAA-HCT5r-9N7NDsVShVqrU6iczhcruUbgs+j8-gCFvwAL6Tfb8PigSCwHaVUxQXBYUSoADCtR84zkqz4cDgpRw+CgxFIeiKJTKVRq9UwTMIzmAKLgwg0EEMCHUlzOWAkYwQpDgzIZ2DwArZHz4qIEOOg8CslR8YkpvgJ7IphtNNIoa3pjLVLMF7Mm1FofWoLHdXEos1FEAA1lqdeA9cbLWGqWaoocLZHrbS7armayUM7XZR3cwfSKRGYHFAg9iQ3iDUbS1bZCEYybqfIbXSVfzHWzDi6aBmmJ6qN7M8MoCxfbmoPnC7qSyaIxXktXLbXlrbGw6UypW+nM27Ox2ONxB01h9AtUA)

Please keep in mind, that order of unions in typescript is tricky.
Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662061/why-element-order-in-union-type-has-changed) and [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17944) issue

You can find more examples in my [blog](https://catchts.com/union-array)