# Ensuring all enum keys are present in an array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm working with TypeScript and I have an enum, let's call it Ej, and an array that I want to ensure contains all the keys of the enum.

```
enum Ej {
    A="A"
    B="B"
}

const ejArr1: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["A", "B"]; // ✅
const ejArr12: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["B", "A"]; // ✅
const ejArr2: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["A"]; // ❌
const ejArr3: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["B"]; // ❌
const ejArr3: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["A", "B", "C"]; // ❌
```

Is there a way to guarantee that the ejArr has all the enum keys at compile time.

Comment: Is `const ejArr = Object.values(Ej)` an option? I doubt this is possible with an array literal.

Comment: @Bergi it is possible however with some  length restrictions. You can create a permutation of all allowed states. Consider [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBY7kw) example

Comment: Related answers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65533827/get-keys-of-an-interface-in-generics/65534971#65534971), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68949858/how-can-i-get-tuple-type-from-the-members-of-another-type-in-typescript/68950848#68950848) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69100938/how-to-declare-an-array-of-exactly-one-alias-declared-in-a-type-alias/69101294#69101294). ALso , you can check my [blog](https://catchts.com/union-array)

Comment: @Bergi the goal is to create arrays with different arrangements so that when a new key is added to the enum, TypeScript will alert that the key needs to be added to those arrays. Therefore, that wouldn't work for me

Comment: Would `["A", "B", "B"]` be valid?

Comment: @captain-yossarian-from-ukraine Your blog's solution is pretty much what I want, but I need it not to guarantee the order, just to ensure that all elements are present in the array. Can you think of a way to achieve that?

Comment: @Behemoth The truth is, for my case, having more elements than there should be or having them repeat doesn't matter to me. I just need to ensure that they are all present in the array, regardless of their order. Although if it also ensures that there are no extra elements or that the elements are guaranteed not to repeat, it will surely be useful for other users in the future. :D

Comment: It's a big difference if you want all tuple permutations with an exact size OR type check if an array contains specific literals.

Comment: @captain-yossarian-from-ukraine I just noticed that in the third update of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65533827/get-keys-of-an-interface-in-generics/65534971#65534971), it's exactly what I need.

Comment: @captain-yossarian-from-ukraine Would you like to leave an answer with update 3 so that I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
// taken from here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-692864087
type TupleUnion<U extends string, R extends any[] = []> = {
  [S in U]: Exclude<U, S> extends never ? [...R, S] : TupleUnion<Exclude<U, S>, [...R, S]>;
}[U];

enum Ej {
  A = "A",
  B = "B",
}

type EnsureAllKeys<T extends string> = TupleUnion<`${T}`>

const ejArr1: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["A", "B"]; // ✅
const ejArr12: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["B", "A"]; // ✅
const ejArr2: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["A"]; // ❌
const ejArr3: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["B"]; // ❌
const ejArr3: EnsureAllKeys<keyof typeof Ej> = ["A", "B", "C"]; // ❌
```

Please take into account that inside `EnsureAllKeys` I have wrapped `T` into template literal string annotation. This hack transforms enum into strings, otherwise you will be prompted to use enums instead of literal strings.