# typescript generate index signature type from 2 union types

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

given

```
type key = "a" | "b" | "c"
type value = 1 | 2 | 3
```

I want to generate `{a:1, b:2, c:3}` using two union types in above

`type A<K,V> = ?????`

what is `?????`

Comment: I don't believe union types in TypeScript are ordered, so I don't think there's a way to do directly what you are trying to do without manually adding some more information about how the different values available to each type are linked together.

Comment: @MarkHanna is right. Unions is unordered data structure. You need use tuples instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it is possible to do.
COnsider this example:

```js
type key = "a" | "b" | "c"
type value = 1 | 2 | 3

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

// credits goes to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
  U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53953814/typescript-check-if-a-type-is-a-union#comment-94748994
type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
  ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
  : [T, ...A];

type Length<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>> = T extends { length: infer L }
  ? L
  : never;

type CompareLength<
  X extends ReadonlyArray<any>,
  Y extends ReadonlyArray<any>
  > = Length<X> extends Length<Y> ? true : false;


type Callback<T, U> = T extends PropertyKey ? U extends PropertyKey ? Record<T, U> : never : never

// https://catchts.com/tuples#zip 
type Zip<
  T extends ReadonlyArray<any>,
  U extends ReadonlyArray<any>,
  Result extends Record<string, any> = {}> =
  (CompareLength<T, U> extends true
    ? (T extends []
      ? Result
      : (T extends [infer HeadT1]
        ? (U extends [infer HeadU1]
          ? Result & Callback<HeadT1, HeadU1>
          : never)
        : (T extends [infer HeadT2, ...infer TailT2]
          ? (U extends [infer HeadU2, ...infer TailU2]
            ? Zip<TailT2, TailU2, Result & Callback<HeadT2, HeadU2>>
            : never)
          : never
        )
      )
    )
    : never);



type Keys = UnionToArray<key>;

type Values = UnionToArray<value>

// Record<"a", 1> & Record<"b", 2> & Record<"c", 3>
type Result = Zip<Keys, Values>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA1hJQLxQEQEMVQD6oEaZxQGMUAoUSKANzQBsBXaZARmygCY2BmU0gej5QiAJwgATAJbAAzlADmAewizgCqAAtgwMNIBcA6cDREYCqhGEAzWgoDuAOiIKAtnzR8ArAAYuAdg-sABwAbOTg0ACqAHYSClEAKgoAklHAFtIQRMCxUQA8EQB8SFAAFBFQEAAeaVFismhRCAD8pTC6UBEAlEhFVAoSYlDtURDmwt1VNXWlpFCw7RJRlhZQSaTdiL39YrNQLWtzw6MWANy8AkKikjLySipqmtp6AnJS6vS4ji58zhIiCtIFJZgHx4uEAMoiCRgEESaTSRjSPjMLjsACcgQAxHCEZkXM4IKkALQAFmCgWYzBJaK8zDClGiOUSAHkqLQ6vkishGXFEik0sIMlkcrlduVJoTpg1mqVLO0uj1qNshlARmNSAUzvToAAFBRgHl5QrFQ0stkc40S2qyEpoBZLFYAQQ2WwGeygjpVatO50EInEUlkimUUFUGi0On0fEMxlMY2sdi%20rgAjojsnEkR4uGisxSSXwKMooTCiUR1JkYESJJYiWgiYWq9Ja0T6DE4pinM4CcS0STfCTAmje9rVtJDbl4lyoABteIAXQq1UlsmnpuSqXSmXTeUnC5aljoGRVwGEjC1hY6bYSCkdwmEaBAE4ANB7F1NZK2YFE7FFpwvkH%20U5JGOV4TkUVrTCejC7C0a63vej4AKKVEQDBiBAz5QHqBqgZOBQvtO2HjpOL72GRjpzgUuztLOpHkXO57hFAAAyhJyMA6gTm%20y5QAAShAaBiHEtAgPBD65NKBRTvE3HWlAADeUC0GxHH2sswgsVAAC%20MEsdRqrHMIjGUAAwi4YBoKIrFROxnG7AAGrJ0z8YJwmiXe4mSU%20uwAJpObILlCVEIliY%20km7FO1m2bk9ngUuclRRxuQ%20UULRQdA7QHrQGRaiOJl0LQuCxphxrIDJEGyDqwj6hYoAANLwO64rxdMVU1cI9WNS0-FOMIYglUURxjF6hm%20uGTxRkQaDAGWMhJgW9BgMp0iYgAXtCUAjgAWtCopzOVLUBQJQUhR5YWNPhYr%20Xxx1uaFEkXd5cz8QitDANdPUKH1uSGMIixyC%20knFPJWlcrsJRmc4FlWSpnHxC%20lqHaGp4QLscwtCUB3vjOc5o3M7ovfQb144cpRYzx06LOpUAABLHfEzC4-jzPumU12Uw6Gl04JESMyTLPdcoRPvQAZFA%20W0IVxXc2IDMvjLvNUSzLNDRYnT86TmPs1TKwy-E7B0fYOsafEaASLQ%20tM8r%20MY812Mc9TCsG1AZFG5zUCm%20bETsFb1s21AO1gBOZsW87nu0N7L6E29UBixLUsmLkevO07UkayrBljOrfuk96wjp9nLOF3MxcjVnuUjg1ICyNyV6JPdcAgJqvAXgAanQiImnXN5nbkNAMBAVH8IIn3fegKAvswRRi6P-UoPgL7sNPN29XPJAvlwVEXtH73IIHuRV9IL7twP0gFEAA)

I have converted both `key` and `value` to tuples and then just merged them.

However, you should not do this in your production code. It is **UNSAFE**.
Please see this [issue/17944](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17944) and my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662061/why-element-order-in-union-type-has-changed).

You should never rely on union order as well as `Object.keys` order.