# How to Transform a Object into an Ordered Set of Discriminated Unions

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

given the following type definition

```
type MailStatus = {
    InvoiceSent?: Date;
    ReminderSent?: { 
        date: Date;
        recipient: string;
    }
    FinalReminderSent?: {
        date: Date;
        recipient: string;
        text: string;
    }
}
```

I'd like to have type where I can define the "order" in which a property is required and which creates a discriminated union which have ever more required properties.

For example

```
type OrderedMailStatus = MagicType<MailStatus, "InvoiceSent" | "ReminderSent" | "FinalReminderSent">
//or this
type OrderedMailStatus = MagicType<MailStatus, ["InvoiceSent", "ReminderSent","FinalReminderSent"]>
```

should yield the following type

```
type OrderedMailStatus =
| {
    kind: "InvoiceSentRequired";
    InvoiceSent: Date;          //InvoiceSent now required
    ReminderSent?: { 
        date: Date;
        recipient: string;
    };
    FinalReminderSent?: {
        date: Date;
        recipient: string;
        text: string;
    };
  }
| {
    kind: "ReminderSentRequired";
    InvoiceSent: Date;          //InvoiceSent required
    ReminderSent: {             //ReminderSent also required
        date: Date;
        recipient: string;
    };
    FinalReminderSent?: {
        date: Date;
        recipient: string;
        text: string;
    };
  }
| {
    kind: "FinalReminderSentRequired";
    InvoiceSent: Date;          //all
    ReminderSent: {             //3 properties
        date: Date;
        recipient: string;
    };
    FinalReminderSent: {       //are required
        date: Date;
        recipient: string;
        text: string;
    };
  }
```

so that I could do the following assignments

```
const s1 = {
    kind: "InvoiceSentRequired",
    InvoiceSent: new Date()
} //OK

const s2 = {
    kind: "ReminderSentRequired",
    InvoiceSent: new Date(),
    ReminderSent: {
        date: new Date(),
        recipient: "Somebody@somewhere.com"
    }
} //OK

const s3 = {
    kind: "FinalReminderSentRequired",
    ReminderSent: {
        date: new Date(),
        recipient: "Somebody@somewhere.com"
    },
    FinalReminderSent: {
        date: new Date(),
        recipient: "Somebody@somewhere.com",
        text: "YOU HAVE TO PAY!"
    }

} //FAILS because it is missing the property InvoiceSent
```

Also important: The types of the properties should be automatically taken what ever they are in the original `MailStatus`. So even in this expanded example you can not make any assumptions which property has which type.

The principle idea behind this question is something along the lines of a `Workflow`. Where in the beginning you have a type whose properties are all optional. As this type travels across the system more and more properties become mandatory

Comment: Fields and `keyof MailStatus` are not ordered (or at least the order is not defined). If you are willing to put the fields in a tuple, we can derive all of the other types from the tuple.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Tuples will do fine

Comment: Neither `keyof SomeType` nor `Object.keys()` nor even js specification gives you a guarantee of `keys` order in a hash map data structure. AFAIK, only `Map.keys()` [gives you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) a collection of keys in order of insertion

Comment: @captain-yossarian - The JavaScript specification defines an order for object properties, it has done for several years. It's not a good idea to *use* it for anything, but it is defined. :-) (And yes, the various `Map` iteration methods -- `keys`, `entries`, `values` -- iterate in insertion order. [For objects, it's more complicated than that -- one reason for not using it. :-) ])

Comment: @robkuz Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/Nlx3ON) works

Comment: @T.J.Crowder wooow, thank you for enlightening me. Could you please give a link?

Comment: @captain-yossarian - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/ ES2015 started the process but didn't define the order for `for-in` or `Object.keys` (which is kind of a problem); subsequent specs defined order for "own" properties and as of ES2020 or ES2021 (I forget which), there's order even for inherited ones. Spec links: [OrdinaryOwnKeys](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys) and [EnumerateObjectProperties](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-enumerate-object-properties). But the rules are complex. The old guidance not to rely on it is arguably just as solid now as ever. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks you very much it is good to know. SO in theory - there is order but in practice it is safer to not rely on it, tight ?

Comment: @captain-yossarian - Yeah, b/c it's so complex and easy to get wrong. (I think all modern engines implement it correctly.) Ex: the objects created by the literals `{x: 1, y: 2}` and `{y: 2, x: 1}` have different orders (`["x", "y"]` and `["y", "x"]`), but `{1: "a", x: 1, 2: "b"}`, `{x: 1, 1: "a", 2: "b"}`, and `{x: 1, 2: "b", 1: "a"}` all have the same order (`["1", "2", "x"]`). But `{5.1: "a", 5.2: "b"}` and `{5.2: "b", 5.1: "a"}` have different orders! (B/c those numbers aren't [array indexes](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#array-index).) Then if you get into inherited properties... :-D

Comment: @robkuz I  think my solution works with the new requirements. Just put the appropriate type instead of day in the tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution to this problem:

```
type Id<T> = {} & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] }

type PickIfNotPrimitive<T, K extends keyof T, V = T[K]> = 
    V extends Date | string | number | bigint | boolean 
        ? Record<K, V>
        : Pick<T, K>
        
type Accumulate<T, Keys extends string[], B = {}, R = never> =
    Keys extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ? 
        Tail extends string[]
            ? Accumulate<
                T, 
                Tail,
                Required<PickIfNotPrimitive<T, Head & keyof T>> & B, 
                // New result
                    | R & Partial<PickIfNotPrimitive<T, Head & keyof T>> // Add new partial values
                    | Required<PickIfNotPrimitive<T, Head & keyof T>> & B & { type: `${Head & string}Required` }>
            : never
        :Id<R>

type X =  Accumulate<MailStatus, [
    "InvoiceSent", 
    "ReminderSent",
    "FinalReminderSent"
]>
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgSwDYGVh2AVwM5QLxQDeAUFGVAJIB2AbgPYIDGEKEVwA-AFxQAiGEANylyAJQgBbBFQAmEAE6t23IlBHlyMgT37Ah6jVHkRGCMAjbAe2YPOkBzYRoC+BgGLS4ScVNkKlnDwkhprafAJOIUYmZhbs1rYOkSF6AB5WUDZ2VI4Grq7EoJCUMgA8ACoAfPhEzlAAZKoA2gAKUNJQANYQIHQAZlDlALo85a1DBUXQLUydFH0AcnTALXZSwAg0EBUANFAA0lAQ6WwyuN29A+V7AGo1Y-tD1QQGd8d6sri60AA+mYk5KB-KiYCQAIwUQKgYIQ9mkwChYLodCQEDgVDUUSgHCg4kYdHkZX2t0qBg0PBmjE6uwOpKxhXA0AAgoxGKDMEgBDT9j1cO9Trgsg4mkM9gAhGqEZx7UQ1KgQLbyZ4GHkgPknT5QJrSPqQgASaJkewAdKadZDyogkENsZiopbkEcNWd-tl7CKyVEcSy2RIOVzPViyNc7UHDA6kDtA0HxABHTAIYxlSlzRbLVYIdabbYhg1wGQNLo9fqDSrVRpivbRrEAehrUAWEAA7tFsBzgNWw1DZY0WnB5BsvKUU-Mlis1ggNlsaXmC40LiWqtU61AmTIC-KW2B+4OkFAaF5MBBsJ2w384wmk8PZqP0xOpzm9rPCwurmXCxLGoQoFMeAADAASQhn0aIUcmcC9EwgGQ-ygZw6S7Hh5UVaMuAoMpRFJBligADRqVdWXZTk9FKeBkDQDAcD2JoDAAImoegmBYSxaKrDRaJ8aQ5EUFio3YjwqC8Ti-B49haOIJ4gA)

We build up in `R` the result one by one. `B` represents the fields that are already required.

I use `Id` just to pretty up the types. Can be removed, but the results are unreadable without it.

Not sure I would recommend actually using this, but it is fun

Comment: Yeah, this works. But it is somehow ugly because now one has to define "the type" as a tuple of partial types. So the question is: can one transform a `record|object` type into a tuple of partial types. But that is maybe a question of its own.

Btw. It is always fun with you guys. totally mind melding

Comment: @robkuz See if this is better :)

Comment: the `Id` type is missing

Answer (score 2):

First of all it worth creating a tuple with expected order of keys:

```js
type Keys = ["InvoiceSent", "ReminderSent", "FinalReminderSent"]
```

Now we need to create an utility type which will iterate through `Keys` tuple and create expected union.

```js
type Union<
    Tuple extends any[],
    Result extends {} = never
    > =
    // Obtain first element from the Tuple
    (Tuple extends [infer Head, ...infer Rest]
        // Check whether this element extends allowed keys
        ? (Head extends keyof MailStatus
            // call Union recursively with Rest
            // and unionize previous Result with newly created discriminated union
            ? Union<Rest, Result | MailStatus & Record<Head, Date> & { kind: `${Head}Required` }>
            : never)
        : Result)
```

Playground

Lets test it:

```js
type Result = Union<Keys>

// ok
const result: Result = {
    kind: 'InvoiceSentRequired',
    InvoiceSent: new Date()
}

// expected error
const result2: Result = {
    kind: 'InvoiceSentRequired',
}

// ok
const result3: Result = {
    kind: 'FinalReminderSentRequired',
    FinalReminderSent: new Date
}
```

Looks like it works

P.S. Don't rely on `keyof` operator if you are interested in some particular order. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17944) and my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662061/why-element-order-in-union-type-has-changed)

Comment: You beat me to it :). had a similar solution: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgSwDYGVh2AVwM4DEERIAm2UAvFANoBQUdUA3lAJIB2AbgPYIDGEKEVsABcUACIZoAXwA0tekwBKEALYJWRCACcBQ0RODS59RlHys4SZWo3bdI8ZKizqAXWqhIUAKqsEnVgAVTjZDLWwIHmB-VgAebwA+cigACm8oCAAPQw1SOFYQKAB+VIBrUW8ASjIErgQiKFFWCHZtSozswRJUlPKodQAzbRZq2u4idpLmRqhm1q0PcGhmIljApIoGKSgAMlNKAAV+1ihSiBBOAahA11FAw9cpRa8AQR4eTBVMJEk1jpzuphWKVWJwAO6sSiuGRQABCyS2G3kdEC-y6pEog2GAAkIHAiDCAHTErFaa6IJCuYpQZEmKBvD5fH6GNYUmG4-G7KDKACOmAQWggq1hST2TE8EFEZwuVw5DW2AB8oAc4FpopZYnLRXCoElhLSTLDqM9oAANZIsVYMz7fX7wZBoDA4fCEEgJBJAA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Finally :D, I have a hard time when you are online :D

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir feel free to publish your solution, my solution does not work as expected

Comment: Why doesn't it work ? 

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I did not test it properly, so required property don\t stack

Comment: I am sorry Sirs! The solution is not correct and additionally my example was not well choosen. I will update the question