# Typing method of a abstract class with an interface

Tags: typescript, methods, abstract-class, function-definition

Consider this trivial example:

```
abstract class Foo {

  public abstract functionAdd(number1, number2, number3): number

  public abstract functionMultiply(number1, number2, number3): number
}

interface Numbers {
  number1: number
  number2: number
  number3: number
}
```

How can I use the interface `Numbers` to describe parameters of both methods? Perhaps there's other - more idiomatic - way of defining abstract methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please keep in mind that `Numbers` contains unordered set of keys, just like HashMap whereas both `functionAdd` and `functionMultiply` expects an ordered tuple of arguments. In other words, These methods expect:

```js
functionAdd(...[number1, number2, number3]:[number, number, number])
```

It means that there is no **safe** way to transform `Numbers` into ordered tuple.

Actualy, [there is a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55127004/how-to-transform-union-type-to-tuple-type) to transform union to tuple but there is no [order guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662061/why-element-order-in-union-type-has-changed) in unions.

SO, I believe you have two options.

1. Either declare `Numbers` as labeled tuple :

```js
type Numbers = [number1: number, number2: number, number3: number]

// and use it
  public abstract functionMultiply(...props:Numbers): number
```

2. Or pass it to functions as is (as object with three props):

```js
interface Numbers {
  number1: number
  number2: number
  number3: number
}

 public abstract functionMultiply({number1, number2, number3}: Numbers): number
```