# Extracting first type from union typescript

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have a `type`:

```
type T1 = "Hello" | "World"
```

I would like to extract the first `type` from the `union`, without knowing what that `type` is. I would like a `type` of the form:

```
type T2 = "Hello"
```

Comment: `Union` - is unordered set of data. There is no `first` and `last` element in the union. - Furthermore, there is no such guarantee. See my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662061/why-element-order-in-union-type-has-changed) and github  [issue#17944](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17944)

Comment: You shouldn't try to do this unless it's just for fun.  There is no guarantee of ordering.

Answer (score 1):

**As multiple people have already mentioned, you should probably not do this in production code.**

You can use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70061272/9549012) with one small change:

```
type UnionToParm<U> = U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never;
type UnionToSect<U> = UnionToParm<U> extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never;
type ExtractParm<F> = F extends { (a: infer A): void } ? A : never;

type SpliceOne<Union> = Exclude<Union, ExtractOne<Union>>;
type ExtractOne<Union> = ExtractParm<UnionToSect<UnionToParm<Union>>>;

type ToTuple<Union> = ToTupleRec<Union, []>;
type ToTupleRec<Union, Rslt extends any[]> = 
    SpliceOne<Union> extends never ? [ExtractOne<Union>, ...Rslt]
    : ToTupleRec<SpliceOne<Union>, [ExtractOne<Union>, ...Rslt]>
;

type test = ToTuple<5 | 6 | "l">;
type firstOfUnion = test[0]
```

You can get the nth type from the union by using `test[n]`

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIAoEMBOBbAHhgD4oBeWKCAD2AjgBMBnKLOEKAfigAoBrAFywAlOVIA3JAgZQhcCOIg4A3AChQkWIhToAyhADGwIqQrxkaTLkIkqtes178hCOADMlUAJKiyEqQyi3F6yUPKKKurg0ACitDhYRtj4BABiplCpdnSMLADevFgu7p4AgsJCktJQAL5cUKWh4UpqUZq6YAA2CAYQAPLyRNpwGXEGnQCuDBBDFgA0UHHACUYDM+YoxMRqGrHxicBrs5vki-tJ1seW+kZX6Mk2w1vbqm3Q6KgTXetPpx9fnQgACVDFcFgBtAC6L12UH+3xBBjBUCBTE6wGyDhYbBAUIyqighKgHW6vSOGxGmNyYQUnm44KWK0OgwpxAWADpOaj0ZCCUShPDAYiCCSev0WU8IYyDuTJVBOezucBoapWrC6EwMRRBTMAKxQAA+UAAbIaoAAiTrml5AA)

Comment: Obligatory link to answer with jcalz's comments about unions to tuples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55128956/18244921

Comment: You should definitely discourage this sort of thing, since it is [unbelievably fragile](https://tsplay.dev/wQxgJW)